# Need a workaround for .position() bug in jquery-ui/ webkit

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, webkit

I have a web page that is, ultimately, a bunch of jquery-ui dialogs, all 30% screen width, in three columns, each containing dashboard information of a different sort.

I load the data into divs, and on the $(document).ready() function, I create the dialogs, and arrange them on top of each other in various columns, depending on the type of data the div is displaying.

I use a variation of this code for each div (I plan on making this cleaner when I get it working right, so please forgive its redundancy).  First I create the dialog if it contains data:

```
//show recent posts if they exist below the account requests
if($('#recentPosts').html().length > 0){
    $('#recentPosts')
    .dialog({
        title: 'Recent Forum Messages',
        height: 320
    })
    .parent().addClass('cfdialog').attr('id', 'recentPostsDialog');
} else {
    $('#recentPosts').addClass('cfdialog').attr('id', 'recentPostsDialog');
}
```

... this is necessary, because I need to be able to grab the entire dialog box (I don't understand why there's no mechanism to easily assign an ID to a dialog div); after all my dialogs are created, I do something like this:

```
//now that the dialogs are set up, position them.
var leftContent = $('#columnTop');
var centerContent = $('#columnTop');
var rightContent = $('#columnTop');

$('.cfdialog')
.css('width', '30%')
.css('height', 'auto')
.css('max-height', '400');

...

$('#recentPostsDialog')
.position({
    my: 'center top',
    at: 'center bottom',
    of: centerContent,
    offset: '0 5'
});
if ($('#recentPostsDialog').html().length > 0){
    centerContent = $('#recentPostsDialog');
}
```

This will display the posts in a dialog box just as I'd like in FireFox and IE.  For Chrome, however, the dialogs pop up about 30 pixels and interfere with my menu items.

I've read quite a few thing on SO and the jquery forums suggesting this is due to the way webkit calculated offsets, and someone posted a patch fix, but it does not seem to work in this situation.

Can someone clue me in on how to get around the problem for webkit-based browsers?

Comment: are you sure dialogs is the right solution for this?

Comment: To be honest, no, I don't think it is, but I also don't think it's my problem in this case.

Comment: It kinda is. You are trying to align absolutely positioned `div`s (which would be attached at the bottom of the `body`) over some other elements. That even sounds wrong and produces exactly the kind of issues I would expect it to. If you are trying to create widgets with collapse/close button, then dialog is really not the right way to go. You probably need something `draggable`, but physically positioned inside your columns.

Comment: This is focused on the `.position()` function, which effectively absolutely positions a div as well.  And it works swimmingly in Firefox and IE.  Regardless of the widget style I use, this behavior is repeatable, reproducible, and there's a lot of people complaining about it;  I am just looking for a workaround, and frankly I'm not positioned to rip out the dialog infrastructure and replace it with something else at this point.

Comment: Try setting the position of the `of` element to relative, if it is not already relative or absolute. Other than that, you may have have to branch browser-dependent code or complain to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem there is no easy answer.  I ended up testing for `jQuery.browser.safari` and if true, manually offset the divs. :(